# Tool to recursivly convert a HMTL file to PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, web-crawler

Are there any tools which not only convert a HTML file to PDF but also follow links, so that in the end I get 1(!) PDF file which contains all html files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a free solution, you could download the site with [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), merge it into 1 file with [SoftSnow Merger](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/SoftSnow_Merger), then print it to PDF with [Bullzip free PDF printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php).

A little bit more work, but at a much lower price :)

Answer (score 1):

[**Adobe Acrobat Pro**](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/) will do this, but at a cost.  I believe they do offer a free trial, which you could take advantage of if you wanted to.

[image]