# Searching for free "html to pdf" software

Tags: pdf, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Html files to Pdf ?](https://superuser.com/questions/122739/how-to-convert-html-files-to-pdf)

I am searching for a free software to convert html to pdf and preserved the html hyperlinks and text searchable in pdf?
Anyone has suggestion?

Edit:
I want Desktop software on Windows xp.
And the software should convert japanese and chinese html to pdf correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar posts: [Pdf to html convertor](http://superuser.com/questions/62169), [Tool to recursivly convert a HMTL file to PDF](http://superuser.com/questions/109257) and [Convert HTML files to PDF](http://superuser.com/questions/306441).

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS X:

- http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/

> **wkpdf** is a command line tool for rendering HTML to PDF using WebKit and RubyCocoa on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thank you! This saved me from .... lots more looking. :P

Comment: After updating to OS X 10.7 Lion, wkpdf has stopped working, with this error:

Comment: `lockFocus sent to a view which is not in a window`. I'm not sure if the 10.7 update is causing this, but that is the primary change to my system and wkpdf doesn't work any longer on any site.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give us more information. Desktop software or web software? For what operating system?

For example, [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) is a nice PHP5 HTML to PDF library that even preserves the CSS styling.

Comment: +1 for dompdf. It's a bit fiddly to get working, especially with images and complex layouts, but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at PDFCreator (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). I am using it and am happy.

Comment: Can it preserve hyperlinks?
I just tried it, seem can't preserve hyperlinks and not clickable.

Comment: @cpps No, it does not preserve hyperlinks. I had the same problem with it.